Why userscript cannot intercept all requests?
Similar to this question. The following userscript intercepts fetch and XMLHttpRequest requests and log their url's to the console. But, why it doesn't intercept all requests? for example it doesn't log: https://www.youtube.com/s/desktop/508deff1/img/logos/favicon.ico and https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/sodar/56-y-0RG.js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YouTube Urls
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  URLs on YouTube.
// @author       me
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // intercept fetch requests
    const originalFetch = window.fetch;

    window.fetch = function(url, options) {

        console.log(url)
        return originalFetch(url, options);
    };


    // intercept XMLHttpRequest
    const originalXhrOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {

        console.log(url)
        return originalXhrOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };

})();

Both resources aren't preloaded:
EDIT:
Here are the initiator of a request, three cases in the same order marked in the image:

For the first one:
(anonymous)         @desktop_polymer.js:7320
zla                 @base.js:1425
nwa                 @base.js:2869
mya                 @base.js:3155
g.k.xz              @base.js:9573
g.k.startRendering  @base.js:9520
.
.
.
g.k.loadVideoByPlayerVars   @base.js:10439
g.k.saa                     @base.js:10612
UR.a.state.j.<computed>     @base.js:4605
(anonymous)                 @desktop_polymer.js:9647
(anonymous)                 @desktop_polymer.js:18592
acquireApi_                 @desktop_polymer.js:18592

(anonymous)                 @desktop_polymer.js:3853
(anonymous)                 @desktop_polymer.js:11370
Ov.resolveCommand           @desktop_polymer.js:5622
fmb                         @desktop_polymer.js:7712
onEndpointClick_            @desktop_polymer.js:7719
(anonymous)                 @desktop_polymer.js:3853

For the second one:

For the third one:
eval                @ VM118:1
gy                  @ VM110:1
t7                  @ VM114:1
eval                @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
Oa                  @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
M5                  @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
X                   @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
eval                            @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
requestIdleCallback.timeout     @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
requestIdleCallback
R3                     @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
M5                     @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
X                      @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
eval                   @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
requestIdleCallback.timeout     @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
requestIdleCallback
R3                     @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
M5                     @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
X                      @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
eval                   @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
requestIdleCallback.timeout     @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
requestIdleCallback
R3                     @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
M5                     @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
X                      @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
eval                   @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
requestIdleCallback.timeout @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
requestIdleCallback
R3                     @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
M5                     @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
X                      @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
eval                   @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
requestIdleCallback.timeout     @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
requestIdleCallback
R3                     @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
M5                     @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
X                      @ 5k7CCto5.html:1
.
.
.
Promise.then
C               @ 5k7CCto5.html:13
D               @ 5k7CCto5.html:13
db              @ 5k7CCto5.html:19
E               @ 5k7CCto5.html:18
(anonymous)             @ 5k7CCto5.html:13
(anonymous)             @ 5k7CCto5.html:41
(anonymous)             @ 5k7CCto5.html:37


Are they being made via XHR or fetch?

Look at the initiator of the request in devtools - it may be a DOM element (not fetch/xhr) or it may be inside the service worker or inside an iframe.

@Kosh idk, neither of the interceptors work on them

@woxxom Actually in the Size field of the Network tab says ServiceWorker router, does that mean the request was made by a service worker and cannot be intercepted?

No. Interception in your code occurs before the request is made, so that router thing is unrelated as it happens only when the request is actually made. Look at the initiator.

@woxxom I added the initiator of the requests, could you please take a look at it?

The screenshot shows 5k7CCto5.html document which means an iframe. You can run your userscript there by adding @match for that URL.
